# Is it possible to Trace a Cold Boot on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

Is it possible to trace a cold boot on Windows 7?  By cold boot I mean the boot you get after a complete shutdown, count to ten, and then press the power switch.  I have been able to trace (enable boot logging) a restart using Process Monitor and Windows Performance Recorder.  However, these appear to have the restart baked in.  I have not been able to trace a cold boot with either of these tools.  Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Why not just turn the PC off after Windows has finished shutting down? There should be some delay during POST.

Comment: From everything I have read it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible for such an application to exist, I did not find any good ones form 3rd parties. The only thing that I know of to be able to trace a booting process from start is XBOOTMGR from MS Windows Performance Toolkit.

Basically, you can use it like in this example:

**xbootmgr –trace boot -traceFlags BASE+LATENCY+DISK_IO_INIT+DISPATCHER+DRIVERS+FILE_IO+FILE_IO_INIT+NETWORKTRACE+PERF_COUNTER+POWER+PRIORITY+REGISTRY -postBootDelay 400 -resultPath C:\TracerLogs**

Note that the command will cause the system to reboot.

Check the parameters/tracerflags in the MS WPT documentation and select what you need.

Also, you can trace a shutdown process, not just a boot one, by using corresponding parameter:
**xbootmgr –trace shutdown**

Comment: I have investigated xbootmgr.  As you say it does a reboot.  This does not go all the way down,  It is another tool, like Windows Performance Recorder that has the restart baked in.  Process Monitor actually does not have a restart baked in as I had said in my original post.  You can exit that tool and then do a manual shutdown and a cold boot.  Although it works fine for a restart, I have not been able to get it to work for the cold boot case.